# Inequality on probability of intersection of n events

Tags: probability

How to prove following inequality on probability of intersection of $n$ events $A_i, i=1,2,3,\ldots,n$.
$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)\right) -(n-1).$$
I have proved it by induction. But how it can be proved in some other way?

Comment: Thanks for editing. Sir may you please prove the inequality ?

Comment: This is the well known Bonferroni's inequality.

Comment: This can be done by induction. For $n=2$: $p(A_1 \cup A_2) = p(A_1) + p(A_2) - p(A_1 \cap A_2) \le p(A_1) + p(A_2) - 1$. Assume case $n$, and derive case $n+1$ similarly to $n=2$, but replace $A_1 = \cup_{i=1}^{n} A_i$ and $A_2 = A_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = 1- P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i^c\right) \\ \geq 1-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c)\right) =1-\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (1-P(A_i))\right) =  \left(\sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)\right) -(n-1)$$

with equality when the $A_i^c$ are mutually disjoint, or at least any  intersections have zero probability since then $P\left(\bigcup_i A_i^c\right) = \sum_i P(A_i^c) $

Comment: The very first equality is incorrect. If $n = 2$, then $p(A_1 \cap A_2) = p(A_1) + p(A_2) - p(A_1 \cup A_2)$.

Comment: @Cuong for $n=2$ the first equality says $P\left(A_1 \cap A_2\right)= 1- P\left(A_1^c \cup A_2^c\right)$  which looks correct to me

Comment: Sorry for my bad. I overlooked the notation superscript $c$.